# JQuery "display:none" being added when cloning outerhtml

Tags: jquery, magento, clone, outerhtml

I have a Magento site where I need to grab the content of a table & use it again elsewhere on the same product page. The issue I'm having is that all works fine on localhost but when I deploy to our dev & live servers. The code is as follows:

```
  $j( window).on('load', function() {
         moveSpecTable();
    });
    function moveSpecTable(){
        console.log('doc ready?');
        if($j('table:first').prop('outerHTML').length){
            console.log("length ");
            try {
                var t = $j('table').html($j('table:first').clone()).html();
              //$j('table:first').prop('outerHTML');

                //$j(t).css("display" , "table");
                $j($j('.add-to-cart-wrapper')).append(t);

            }catch (err){
                console.log('ERROR');
            }
        }

        console.log(t);
        return false;
    }
```

The output on my local MAMP server is as follows:

```
<table border="0">
```

The output on the live/dev servers is as follows:

```
        <table style="display: none;" border="0">
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? The same result whether I use clone or outerhtml.

Thanks

Comment: Does the original table have `display: none`?

Comment: Hi, no its as follows: <table border="0">

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out why this was happening so changed my approach.

/**
     * Re-render the spec table */

```
$j( window).on('load', function() {

    moveSpecTable();
});
function moveSpecTable(){
    if($j('table:first').prop('outerHTML').length){
        try {
            var t = '<table style="display:table; border: 0;">';
            var t1 = $j('table:first').prop('innerHTML');
            var t2 ='</table>';
            var res = t.concat(t1, t2);
            $j($j('.add-to-cart-wrapper')).append(res);
        }catch (err){
            console.log('ERROR');
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I knew from testing that grabbling the innerHtml didn't result in "display:none" being added to the table. So I just concatenate the table start & end to the innerHtml & boom. This works as I want it to. Not too smart but ....